# How to avoid URL length limit in IE7?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need to send URL string more then 2300 chars using javascript. How to avoid the URL length limit in IE7. I know URL length limit is 2048 in IE. But i need to avoid. Give me solution.

Comment: Maybe a POST request? Where do you need to send the string to?

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to do that is sending your data via POST method.